# How to use return value from function returning Future(Either[A, B]) in scala?

Tags: scala, future, either

I have the below function.

```
def get(id: Int): Future[Either[String, Item]] = {
    request(RequestBuilding.Get(s"/log/$id")).flatMap { response =>
      response.status match {
        case OK => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[Item].map(Right(_))
        case BadRequest => Future.successful(Left(s"Bad Request"))
        case _ => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String].flatMap { entity =>
          val error = s"Request failed with status code ${response.status} and entity $entity"
          Future.failed(new IOException(error))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to call this function but I am not sure how to know whether it is returning a String or Item. Below is my failed attempt.

```
Client.get(1).onComplete { result =>
        result match {
          case Left(msg) => println(msg)
          case Right(item) => // Do something
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onComplete` takes a function of type `Try` so you would have to double match on `Try` and in case of success on `Either`

```
Client.get(1).onComplete {
  case Success(either) => either match {
    case Left(int) => int
    case Right(string) => string
  }
  case Failure(f) => f
}
```

much easier though would be to map the future:

```
Client.get(1).map {
  case Left(msg) => println(msg)
  case Right(item) => // Do something
}
```

and in case you want to handle the `Failure` part of `onComplete` use a `recover` or `recoverWith` after mapping on the future.

Comment: `onComplete` returns `Unit` not `Try`. It takes a function that has argument of type `Try`.